# angular scrollstart and scrollstop don't fire in directive, scroll does

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I have a directive as below:

```
.directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {
  return {
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollPosition'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var windowEl = angular.element($window);

      var scrollhandler = function() {
        console.log("scrolling")
      }

      var starthandler = function() {
        console.log("scrolling start")
      }

      var stophandler = function() {
        console.log("scrolling end")
      }

      windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, scrollhandler));
      windowEl.on('scrollstart', scope.$apply.bind(scope, starthandler));
      windowEl.on('scrollstop', scope.$apply.bind(scope, stophandler));
    }
  };
});
```

With HTML:

```
<div id="imageHolder" style="opacity: {{scroll}}" scroll-position="scroll">
```

The only event that fires is the 'scroll' event. I need the other two events and not this, as I am working on mobile and scroll events don't fire until the scrolling stops on mobile (see here http://andyshora.com/mobile-scroll-event-problems.html)

I need to do something custom on start and on end.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you help me understand where you are seeing a "scrollstart" and "scrollstop" events? I've never heard of those. Are they jQuery events?

Comment: Yes, on the jqueryLite docs in angular it says 'on' is available. I'm not sure if these events are available though, I've looked around and found no info (hence I'm here). I'm assuming there must technically be a way in Angular to detect these.

Comment: This is literally the only thing I can find on a "scrollstart" event anywhere: http://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstart/ This event is specifically in jQuery Mobile (an entirely different library). It doesn't seem to be included in jQuery (or, by extension, jqLite that's built in to angular).

Comment: Interesting, you're right, it is jquery mobile. They say on the docs "Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing them to apply when the scroll finishes. We're currently investigating ways to allow DOM manipulations to apply before a scroll starts." so that wont work :( Is it impossible in 2014 to detect the start or end of a scroll? madness

Comment: That certainly is possible. Look into how debouncers work, e.g. the lodash/underscore debouncer. To catch the event start is trivial as its the first event fired. You can get the end event by saying if you don't catch an event within X ms, you consider the scroll to have finished. Finding a appropriate X value might depend on several factors. Ask this question on stackoverflow, and I / others can answer it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bengro's idea of using a timer to determine when the scroll has ended you could do something like this:

```
angular.module('App').directive('scroll',function(){
var timer = null;
return{
  scope:{
  },
  link: function (scope, element) {

 var stophandler = function() {
    console.log("scrolling end")
  }

   var starthandler = function() {
    console.log("scrolling start")
  }

    angular.element(element).bind('scroll', function () {

      scope.$apply.bind(scope, starthandler)

      clearTimeout(timer);

      timer = setTimeout(function () {
          scope.$apply.bind(scope, stophandler)
        }, 1500);

    });
  }
 };
});
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to fire the start and stop events, you bind to the methods, but never call them....

Comment: I just realised it was me that asked this question!